# Using react-beautiful-dnd with Shadow DOM

Tags: shadow-dom, react-beautiful-dnd

I have the issue when working with Microfrontend that it use Shadow DOM so there is no way till now I can use react-beautiful-dnd with Shadow DOM. Does everyone have an idea or any other library?
There is an issue that is still open now: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1659
Thank you guys so much!

Comment: It has been fixed by casieber https://github.com/casieber/react-beautiful-dnd

Answer (score 0):

[react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/casieber/react-beautiful-dnd) did it! It supported shadowDOM for all features of react-beautiful-dnd